# How to apply an annotation to a Koin module dependency declaration?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, koin

I have the following Koin module:

```
val exampleModule = module {
    single<ExampleRepository> { RealExampleRepository() }
}
```

I need to apply two annotations to `RealExampleRepository` to supress an experimental coroutines API usage warning.

The annotations I need to apply are:

```
@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it can be done by converting the module to a method and applying the annotations to the method like so:

```
@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun exampleModule() = module {
    single<ExampleRepository> { RealExampleRepository() }
}
```